# Mini game forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a mini game in C# (windows forms), like space invaders. The spacecraft flies well, but I'm not getting multiple shots, I have a method `timer_Tick` to make the animation, when I press space to shoot, the first shot works fine, but the second shot. The first shot in this half position disappears. The shots are `pictureBox` and I tried List of `pictureBox`, but without success.

I have something like this:

```
    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        shootP = new PictureBox();
        shootP.Image = Properties.Resources.shoot_1;
        shootP.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        shootP.Size = new Size(10, 72);  
        ListShoot = new List<PictureBox>();      
        int i = -1;
    }
     private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
     {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
        control = false;
        i++;
        ListShoot.Add(shootP);
        timeShoot.Start();
     }

      private void timeShoot_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        if (control == false)
        {   
            ListShoot[i].Location = new Point(spacecraft._imageBox.Location.X + 50, spacecraft._imageBox.Location.Y - 55);  // align the shoot with spacecraft
            control = true;     
        }

            ListShoot[i].Top -= 40;
      }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you must add ListShoot[i].Location = new ... right after ListShoot.Add(shootP) and remove the if(control == false) clause completely since it is called once

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new image each time, like in aliassce's answer.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
    {
      control = false;
      shootP = new PictureBox();
      shootP.Image = Properties.Resources.shoot_1;
      shootP.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
      shootP.Size = new Size(10, 72);
      ListShoot.Add(shootP);
      timeShoot.Start();
    }
 }
```

Then you need to update the position of all of the images in your List. Use a foreach loop and ditch the int iterator.

```
private void timeShoot_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (control == false)
    {   
       foreach PictureBox shot in ListShot
       {
           shot.Location = new Point(spacecraft._imageBox.Location.X + 50, spacecraft._imageBox.Location.Y - 55);  // align the shoot with spacecraft
           shot.Top -= 40;
       }
       control = true;
    }
  }
```

You might have to update your code that draws the images to loop through the List as well. with something like:

```
foreach PictureBox shot in ListShoot
{
   draw(shot);
}
```

Finally you'll probably want to clean out the list every now and then to get rid of any shots that are no longer on the screen and don't need to be updated or drawn anymore.

Comment: Thank you Lord... But, the method Timer_tick repeats itself, the shot.top -= 40; need to be rum several times to shot up. i make this.
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {  

tiroP.Location = new ....

}
Timer...
 foreach (PictureBox shot in ListTiro)
                {
                    shot.Top -= 40;
                    Controls.Add(shot);
                }

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same PictureBox. You can try creating a new one.
Add this cone into `Form1_KeyDown`.

```
    shootP = new PictureBox();
    shootP.Image = Properties.Resources.shoot_1;
    shootP.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    shootP.Size = new Size(10, 72);
```

On the other hand you should use OOP as soon as possible

Comment: Oh God... Worked, but, on second shoot, the first stop on the way

Comment: Since @StefanGriffiths has not enough rep to post a comment I posted his question as a comment for him: 

I'm currently doing this project now in university, i was just wandering in the code displayed above what is "shootp." in you space invaders game